# Converting some Swift code to C# Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, porting

How can I convert some swift code like this to C# Xamarin.iOS please:

> guard
>         let configurationFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "client", withExtension: "conf"),
>          let configurationFileContent = try? Data(contentsOf: configurationFileURL)
>      else {
>          fatalError()
>      }

Is Swift so much better/shorter to load a file content than C#? Thanks

Comment: var data = File.ReadAllText(path);

Comment: Thanks very much, just 1 more question, about funcs...are these, just regular methods, or event handlers, and how to port if they are part of an **extension AdapterTests: AdapterDelegate** and named like this _func Adapter(adapter: Adapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings, completionHandler: @escaping (AdapterPacketFlow?) -> Void)_  and _func Adapter(adapter: Adapter, handleEvent event: AdapterEvent, message: String?)_ as they both have a different signature than an event handler in C# which accepts sender and eventArgs (or something derived).

Comment: Please tart a new question for the question about funcs.

Comment: Thanks for your help and here's the follow up which I may have gonne a bit overboard with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608796/how-to-port-a-network-extension-packettunnelprovider-class-from-obj-c-to-Xamarin (but I wanted to try and do some of the work myself too and not just pester someone else). Thanks in advance either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// Get the path to the resource file
var configurationFileURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("client", "conf");
// Make sure the file exists 
if (configurationFileURL != null)
{
    // load the text content of the file into a string variable declared elsewhere
    configurationFileContent = File.ReadAllText(configurationFileURL);
}
```

And to answer "Is Swift so much better/shorter to load a file content than C#?" 
Probably not, but I have not done a performance test to verify.